# Transformation and export from R of a ggplot map to raster file (tiff)

Tags: raster, rasterio, rasterizing, kriging, rasterize

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
.[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Can you please help me with this situation?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxp7D.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUm8B.png